# Datepicker validation not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I have added a datepicker to a popup in  my application which works fine, But when I try to submit the form I am not able to save the entries .My form validator returns false even though there is a valid date in the input text, But if I change the date then form validator returns true..
    This is my code

```
<p class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" ng-click="open($event)" class="form-control registration-input"
                                                datepicker-popup="{{format}}"  show-button-bar="false" 
                                                ng-model="CompanyData.dateOfRegistration" name="dateOfRegistration"
                                                is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" /> <span
                                                class="input-group-btn">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                                    ng-click="open($event)">
                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </span>
                                        </p>
```

> Below is the js code

```
// Disable weekend selection
    $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
      return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
    };

  $scope.dates = [{date:'01-05-2001'}, {date:'05-05-2014'}, {date:'10-11-2008'}]
    $scope.open = function($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();
      $event.stopPropagation();

      $scope.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
      formatYear: 'yy',
      startingDay: 1,
      showWeeks:'false'
    };


    $scope.format = 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'
```

Can anyone tell me what shuld I do in order to make this work..

Comment: I would say that you are initially binded just formatted date string to `ng-model` where as datepicker needs date object, you could look at this [githhub issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4559) which I logged last year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My form validator returns false even though there is a valid date in the input text ?

It's because of ngModel `CompanyData.dateOfRegistration` is not set initially and it is `undefined` which is false.

Even there valid date in datepicker but because `ngModel` is not initialised it is `return false;`

Set the `CompanyData.dateOfRegistration` to valid date.